# Integrating magento and pos

Tags: magento-1.9, pos

I am having magento store and also POS . I need to integrate both , so is there any tool or any extension available in magento for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Check the links b below and select extension according to your need

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=POS&pl=0

P.S. Google before you post Question

Comment: Thanks for the response , that pluggins works with their POS i need to integrate our own POS , so need suggestion on this